Dagster Op with argument
I want my job to be able to call an op and provide it with an argument.
@job
def myJob():
    myOp("1")
    myOp("2")

The docs don't seem to cover this in a simple manner.
I'm expecting to be able to call the same op multiple times in my job but each time with a different argument.
